# Filter undefined columns in Nodejs Waterline ORM?

Tags: node.js, waterline

I added new field: role to my existing User table in the Nodejs Waterline ORM. Now, I am trying to filter those rows have that undefined field.  I wrote following codes, but getting always the empty array.

```
User.find({where:{role: undefined}}).exec(function(err, users) {
   console.log(users);
});
```

Comment: You could try changing *undefined* to *null*. What database system do you use? I'm not sure if a system like MySQL or PostgreSQL has an 'undefined' type.

Comment: I tried with null but it doesn't work